# How to get data just first time in Fragment on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my application I have one `activity` and in this activity I have 3 `fragments` and show this `fragments` with `ViewPager`.
In **fragment #1** I send request to server for get some data and set into **fragment #1** view.

When run first time show this fragment, show loading and get data. **But** when scrolling between fragments and received to **fragment #1**, again show loading and send request data.

**I want just first time send request to server and show loading, when scrolling between fragments and not send this request to server again!**

**My codes in Fragment #1 :**

```
public class SerialDetailInfoFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.infoSerialFrag_castRecyclerView)
RecyclerView infoSerialFrag_castRecyclerView;
@BindView(R.id.epGuideSerialFrag_relatedNewsLay)
RelativeLayout epGuideSerialFrag_relatedNewsLay;
@BindView(R.id.epGuideSerialFrag_relatedNewsRecyclerView)
RecyclerView epGuideSerialFrag_relatedNewsRecyclerView;
@BindView(R.id.epGuideSerialFrag_loadingContent)
AVLoadingIndicatorView epGuideSerialFrag_loadingContent;
@BindView(R.id.infoSerialFrag_addWatchList)
FloatingActionButton infoSerialFrag_addWatchList;

private SerialDetailSendData SendData;
private int serialID;
private String serialImage, chipKey;
private KeyListener variable;
private GoldenGlobeDialogAdapter goldenGlobeDialogAdapter;
private AwardModelAdater awardModelAdapter;
private WhoWatchedAdapter whoWatchedAdapter;
private CastAdapter castAdapter;
private RelatedNewsAdapter relatedNewsAdapter;
private List<Award> awardModel = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Result> whoWatchedModel = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Star> starModel = new ArrayList<>();
private List<NewsDatum> newsModel = new ArrayList<>();
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;

public SerialDetailInfoFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_serial_detail_info, container, false);
    //Initialize
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    context = getActivity();
    seriesActivity = (SeriesDetailActivity) getActivity();
    variable = infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitchText.getKeyListener();
    relatedNewsAdapter = new RelatedNewsAdapter(context, newsModel);
    //Get serial id
    serialID = seriesActivity.getSerialID();
    //Get Collapsing
    isCollapsing = seriesActivity.getCollapsing();
    //Change rate textView
    infoSerialFrag_GenreRateSeekBar.setOnProgressChangeListener(new DiscreteSeekBar.OnProgressChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar, int value, boolean fromUser) {
            infoSerialFrag_GenreRateText.setText(value + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    hideView(infoSerialFrag_contentLay);

    getData();
    getRelatedNews();

    return view;
}
```

**My ViewPager codes:**

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new SerialDetailInfoFragment(), context.getResources().getString(R.string.info));
    adapter.addFrag(new SerialDetailEpGuildFragment(), context.getResources().getString(R.string.episodesGuide));
    adapter.addFrag(new SerialDetailReviewFragment(), context.getResources().getString(R.string.reviews));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

How can I it? please help me my friends <3

Comment: Post your ViewPager adapter code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your ViewPager setup.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Your `setupViewPager` method would look like this:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new SerialDetailInfoFragment(), context.getResources().getString(R.string.info));
    adapter.addFrag(new SerialDetailEpGuildFragment(), context.getResources().getString(R.string.episodesGuide));
    adapter.addFrag(new SerialDetailReviewFragment(), context.getResources().getString(R.string.reviews));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

---

The default behavior for the ViewPagers is to keep 1 Fragment in memory on the left and right of the active fragment so, in order for you to avoid doing the request again, you can maintain the Fragment alive by increasing this value.

This is the documentation of the [setOffscreenPageLimit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) method

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>
> This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
>   of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in
>   place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in
>   perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have
>   a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once,
>   less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as
>   the user pages back and forth.
>
> You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex
>   layouts. This setting defaults to 1.

If you set it up with a value of 3, the Android System will keep all your Fragments alive.

Answer (score 0):

Well  yo can set a boolean and set it to true by default and after first time change it to false.make an if for that to call the methods.

you can even store your defined variable in SharedPrefrences if you want to have the boolean's value even if the user exits the app and returns in future.

SharedPrefrence value will be kept until the app is uninstalled by the user.